# Vuex: unknown action type:

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a problem about how to dispatch action in Vuex.


Now I'm making an app and using Vuex.

I want to dispatch vuex **signin** action in **store/user.js** from **Login.vue**,but  it's not working.I want you to give me any tips.


Now it's the app's directory constructure.


[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVLnQ.png)

And the files which can contain problems are here:

**index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import user from './modules/user'

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
modules: {
    user
}
})

export default store;
```

**user.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import axios from 'axios'
Vue.use(Vuex);

const user = new Vuex.Store({

state: {
    current: null,
    name: 'John'
},
mutations: {
    setCurrent(state, payload) {
        state.current = payload
    }
},
actions: {
    signin({commit}, {name, password}) {
        axios.$post('http://localhost:3000/login', {name, password})
            .then((response) => {
                commit('setCurrent', response.data)
            })
        },  
   signout({commit}) {
        commit('setCurrent', null)
    } 
}
})

export default user;
```

**Login.vue**

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-card>
      <v-card-title>
        Login
      </v-card-title>
      <v-card-text>
        <v-form>
          <v-text-field
            v-model="name"
            :counter="10"
            label="name"
            required
          ></v-text-field>
          <v-text-field
            v-model="password"
            :counter="10"
            label="password"
            required
          ></v-text-field>
          <v-btn
            class="mr-4"
            @click="submitLoginDatas()"
          >
            Login
          </v-btn>
        </v-form>
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
    {{ getName }}
    <v-row class="button">
      <v-col>
        <v-btn
          style="margin-top: 4px;"
          to="/signup"
        >
          Signup
        </v-btn>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
    data() {
      return {
        name: '',
        password: ''
      }
    },
    methods: {
      async submitLoginDatas() {
        console.log('HI')
        console.log(this.$store.state.user.name)
        // ここまでは呼ばれてる
        // store自体も登録できている(下のgetNameから確認できる)
        await this.$store.dispatch("signin",
          {
            name: this.name, 
            password: this.password
          }
        )
      }
    },
    computed: {
      getName() {
        return this.$store.state.user.name
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**What I checked by now**

・typo...ex.express **actions** as **action** like this

・namespace...now I don't express **namespaced:true** in user.js, but I tried **namespaced: true** in **user.js** with the below code. But it didn't work.

```
this.$store.dispatch("user/signin", {
    name: this.name,
    password: this.password
})
```

・user.js is registered correctly in index.js or not

...getName() in computed in Login.vue is working, so maybe it's ok.


・whether actions and mutations are written as object, not function

...maybe it's correct.



Thank you for reading. My question is the reason why this error

```
[vuex] unknown action type: signin
```

has been occuring and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use Vuex inside another Vuex - this is not going to work. Your Vuex module(s) should export a plain object instead of Vuex instance. Please change `modules/user.js` to be

```js
import axios from 'axios'

export default {

state(): {
  return {
    current: null,
    name: 'John'
  }
},
mutations: {
    setCurrent(state, payload) {
        state.current = payload
    }
},
actions: {
    signin({commit}, {name, password}) {
        axios.$post('http://localhost:3000/login', {name, password})
            .then((response) => {
                commit('setCurrent', response.data)
            })
        },  
   signout({commit}) {
        commit('setCurrent', null)
    } 
}
}
```